# How to make full calendar month and year in dropdown selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a full calendar and I need to show its month and year in dropdown list, I know this question is already asked but still not answered there. I am new to full calendar and as per as i know it is updated now hope there is some easiest way to achieve rather than giving it gotodate option. I have created code pen for the calendar if anyone has done this before then please update my codepen and give me link thank you so much...
 [demoToEdit](http://codepen.io/sud/pen/LNvZmv)
Below is my code I have added some of the functions of full calendar as you see I am not able to get on which event I should right dropdown year and month so I have not done it.

```
$(window).load(function(){

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
        for (var i = 0; i<= event.products.length - 1; i++) {
            element.append('<span>'+event.products[i].name+'<span>');    
        };

    },

    events: [
                {
                    title: 'EventName',
                    start: '2016-05-02',
                    products:[
                                {

                                    name:'ProductName'
                                }
                            ]
                },
                {
                    title: 'Event',
                    start: '2016-05-03',
                    products:[
                                {

                                    name:'ProductName1'
                                },
                                {

                                    name:'ProductName2'
                                },
                                {

                                    name:'ProductName3'
                                },
                            ]
                },
                {
                    title: 'EventName',
                    start: '2016-05-13',
                    products:[
                                {

                                    name:'ProductName1'
                                },
                                {

                                    name:'ProductName2'
                                }
                            ]
                },
                {
                    title: 'Event',
                    start: '2016-05-15',
                    products:[
                                {

                                    name:'ProductName'
                                }
                            ]
                },
                {
                    title: 'EventNAme',
                    start: '2016-05-21',
                    products:[
                                {

                                    name:'ProductName1'
                                },
                                {

                                    name:'ProductName2'
                                }
                            ]
                },
                {
                    title: 'Event',
                    start: '2016-05-23',
                    products:[
                                {

                                    name:'ProductName1'
                                },
                                {

                                    name:'ProductName2'
                                }
                            ]
                },
                {
                    title: 'Eventname',
                    start: '2016-05-25',
                    products:[
                                {

                                    name:'ProductName'
                                }
                            ]
                },
                {
                    title: 'Event',
                    start: '2016-05-29',
                    products:[
                                {

                                    name:'ProductName'
                                }
                            ]
                }
            ],
            dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
           console.log('date'+date.format('DD/MMM/YYYY')+"allDay"+allDay.title+"jsEvent"+jsEvent+"view"+view)
    }


}); 
})



[1]: http://codepen.io/sud/pen/LNvZmv
```

Comment: a fiddle, bin, pen is nice, but try always to add the code right within your question - only the bugging part - (so we don't have to do it for you)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion I will do it now wait

Comment: You want to change your date according to 2 dropdowns? year and month?

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to insert drop downs using fullcalendar custom buttons. I simply make header option to false and created custom header myself. Then you can insert any thing to header part and bind events to  those buttons and call appropriate fullcalendar function. example functions that available are

prev (),
next (),
prevYear (),
nextYear (),
today (),
gotoDate ()

Comment: U have create any demo or useble link