# full calendar header options as drop down navigation

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have to put fullcalendar header options(i.e Day view, Week view and Monthly view) in a drop down menu. After selecting one of this option, it'll go to particular one. How can we customise this ? Any one have idea about how to do this ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? I think you just need to make your own dropdown list with appropriate options, and when someone selects an option, run https://fullcalendar.io/docs/changeView to set fullCalendar to the right view. But to me this sounds less user-friendly than the buttons which fullCalendar provides for changing view: With a list of buttons, the user must only click once to change the view, but with a dropdown list, they must click twice (once to open the list, and once to select). So it makes the process slower and more fiddly. Why do you want/need to change it like this??

Comment: It was requirement and i need to more options(user_event-day,user_event-week, company_event-day, company_event-week) to drop down menu and it looks elegant. I will try with Change View function

Comment: @ADyson currently i'm trying with this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242666/how-to-make-full-calendar-month-and-year-in-dropdown-selectable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the drop down navigation, you need to make header as false and you have to pull navigation bar HTML code from browser and put in HTML file. You should call full calendar with those navigation bar classes and it'll work fine. Here is my working code pen, please check it.
    [full calendar drop down menu navigation](https://codepen.io/mahesh-babu-the-flexboxer/pen/omNKrX?editors=1010)

**HTML file**

```
<div class="fc-toolbar">
  <div class="fc-left">
    <div class="fc-button-group">
      <button class="fc-prev-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-left" 
       type="button">
        <span class="fc-icon fc-icon-left-single-arrow"></span>
      </button>
      <button class="fc-next-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner- 
      right" type="button">
         <span class="fc-icon fc-icon-right-single-arrow"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <button class="fc-today-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-left 
       fc-corner-right fc-state-disabled">today</button>
 </div>
 <div class="fc-right">
    <div class="fc-button-group">
      <select id="my-select">
         <option class="fc-agendaDay-button fc-button fc-state-default fc- 
           corner-right">agendaDay</option>
         <option class="fc-agendaWeek-button fc-button fc-state- 
          default">agendaWeek</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="fc-center">
   <h2>January 2019</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="fc-clear"></div>
</div>
```

**JS file**

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.fc-prev-button').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('prev');
  });
  $('.fc-next-button').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next');
  });
  $('.fc-today-button').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('today');
  });
  $("#my-select").click(function(e){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 
      this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text);
  })

 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: false,
   defaultView: 'agendaDay',
   editable: true,
   eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
      for (var i = 0; i<= event.products.length - 1; i++) {
         element.append('<span>'+event.products[i].name+'<span>');    
      };   
   },
   events: [
            {
                title: 'EventName',
                start: '2019-01-23',
                products:[
                            {

                                name:'ProductName'
                            }
                        ]
            },
            {
                title: 'Event',
                start: '2019-01-23',
                products:[
                            {

                                name:'ProductName'
                            }
                        ]
            },
            {
                title: 'EventNAme',
                start: '2019-01-22',
                products:[
                            {

                                name:'ProductName1'
                            },
                            {

                                name:'ProductName2'
                            }
                        ]
            },
            {
                title: 'Event',
                start: '2019-01-23',
                products:[
                            {

                                name:'ProductName1'
                            },
                            {

                                name:'ProductName2'
                            }
                        ]
            },
            {
                title: 'Eventname',
                start: '2019-01-23',
                products:[
                            {

                                name:'ProductName'
                            }
                        ]
            },
            {
                title: 'Event',
                start: '2019-01-24',
                products:[
                            {

                                name:'ProductName'
                            }
                        ]
            }
        ],
        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

      }   

    }); 
  })
```

Comment: This is very helpful and it worked very well. Accepted as answer@mahesh